# nginx: HSTS on a page with www-authentication

Tags: nginx, https

Is it possible, on nginx, to send a Strict-Transport-Security header, even on pages that require WWW-Authentication?

When I have both `auth_basic` and `add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=2592000";`, the HSTS header isn't sent:

```
$ curl -Ik https://****************
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Sun, 14 Sep 2014 17:56:08 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 203
Connection: keep-alive
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="*********"
```

it *is* sent on a different page, that does not require authentication, so the `add_header` directive is having effect - just not when it requires authentication.

Comment: What is the full nginx configuration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of Nginx 1.7.5, released 16 September 2014, this is easily accomplished by adding the "`always`" flag to your `add_header` directive. Extra modules no longer required. :-)

```
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=2592000" always;
```

As the [`add_header` documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) now explains:

> If the `always` parameter is specified (1.7.5), the header field will be added regardless of the response code.

From one of my own web applications (edited):

```
$ curl -I https://example.com/
HTTP/1.1 401 UNAUTHORIZED
Server: nginx/1.11.3
Date: Wed, 31 Aug 2016 15:37:59 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 17
Connection: keep-alive
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="example"
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
```

Answer (score 5):

It is possible, but not with the `add_header` directive, because it doesn't do anything in the case of 401 Unauthorized response.

Description for the add_header directive in the `ngx_http_headers_module` [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html) says:

> Adds the specified field to a response header provided that the
>   response code equals 200, 201, 204, 206, 301, 302, 303, 304, or 307. A
>   value can contain variables.

To send HSTS header on every page, you will have to compile nginx with the [ngx_headers_more](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersMoreModule) module (or just install `nginx-extras` package if you are using Debian), and add the following line to your nginx config file:

```
more_set_headers "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
```